# Which toolkit to use for 3D MMO game development?

Tags: networking, mmo, ogre, irrlicht

Lately i've been thinking about which path to follow for developing an 3D Online game.
I have googled a lot but i couldnt find a good article that covers both game development and online server & client development in same context.
This question has been in mind for about 2 weeks now.
So.. yesterday i started developing a game from scratch by using
Irrlicht.Net Wrapper to use Socket library of .NET which im already familiar.
But i found out .Net wrapper of Irrlicht is not totally finished yet and still have lacks from the original.
So i lost all my motives :/.

So i thought why not to ask the experts before i run into another dead end...

What Game Engine and Networking Library is best way to go for 3D MMO Development?

Here is some of my early conclusions:
Please let me know the ones im wrong.

C++:

- Best Performance for 3D Graphics.
- Most Game Engines has native C++ Libraries.
- Lacks a Solid Socket Library
- .NETC++ Lacks Intellisense Support.

C#:

- Intellisense Support
- NET Socket Library
- Lacks 3D Graphics Performance
- Lacks a native solid 3D Game Engine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quickest/cheapest way to get up and running would be to use the Unity engine for the client, and something like [Photon](http://exitgames.com/Photon/Unity) as your socket server backend.

If you're looking for something with more off-the-shelf support, there's things like [Hero Engine](http://www.heroengine.com/).

If you're asking which language to use, I'm assuming you're not experienced enough to pull off starting from scratch.

Comment: im not looking for the easiest solution , im ok with studying hard and learning new stuff.my intention is not only to develop a game but also learn the craft :).But i dont want to spend time using wrong toolkits that's why i asked :)

Comment: i did the easy way with Acknex(3DGS) when i was back in high school 3 years ago, now im a CS student so i wanna take it to a next level.

Comment: anyway i will accept your answer and try those tools you recommended if i dont like im thinking about irrlicht with c++

Comment: Well don't feel obligated to accept my answer if it doesn't provide the information that you feel you need.  Other people may have different answers.

Comment: As question is closed I just say that Irrlicht & C++ has actually been used in two (more or less successful) indie "MMORPG"-style games.